# How to use the Semantic Tag in Html5?

Tags: html, tags

Can some one explain me, what I should use ?

**div** or **semantic** tag.

> I see many dev use div in html5 doc.

Can you make me understand?

Comment: what can I do now as it is duplicate ?

Comment: thanks,  I was unable to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already know div is a block level element and html5 semantic tags are also & some of them not.

**Its better to use semantic tag** Cause this is the new feature of semantic tag to make reader clear about your code,  I mean markup.

*So, the answer is:*

> Use semantic whenever possible but if you need div /span you can use
>   them.